# Netty - Make all created buffers be little-endian by default

Tags: java, netty, endianness

I need to create channelbuffers in Netty in little-endian byte format by default, and to what I understand I use this piece of code.

```
bootstrap.setOption("child.bufferFactory", new HeapChannelBufferFactory(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN));
```

However when I created new channel buffers, they are big-endian, and thus I must make them little-endian manually.

Is there a way to make all channel buffers be little-endian by default?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I'm creating buffers like such:

```
ChannelBuffer opcodeBuffer = ChannelBuffers.buffer(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN, 4);
```

If I create them like this

```
ChannelBuffer opcodeBuffer = ChannelBuffers.buffer(4);
```

They are not little-endian

Comment: This should work. Is this a `ClientBootstrap` or a `ServerBootstrap`?

Comment: A server bootstrap. I print out the byte order of the bufferfactory and it says little-endian, however if I say make 2 buffers, one with a littleendian byte order, and one just normally, they say byte order mismatch. I have to manually make all of them little endian, and then ill get the correct packet creation.

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting that you are using is for configuring the buffers created by `Channel` objects in your app. This means that every backing buffer created by Netty will be little endian.

`ChannelBuffers` is a static helper class which cannot use the configuration from the bootstrap. If you check the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffers.html#buffer%28int%29), you can see that the methods which don't take a `ByteOrder` say that they are making big-endian buffers explicitly.

So, if you are making the buffers manually, make sure to use the right endianness. Alternatively, you can use one of the `ChannelBufferFactory` implementations in your code to be able to switch easily (if needed).

Comment: I know it seems crude, but would I be able to just edit the channelbuffers class to always make littleendian buffers?

Comment: Not with breaking a lot of code that depends on it making big-endian ones. I'm afraid you'll have to live with it :).

Comment: Yeah, I've changed my code around and got to be much faster and better. Previously I wasn't making the channelbuffers in my messagecodecs little-endian. Now I'm doing that and i don't have the overhead of flipping it later in my encoder class.